# angular - *ngFor with index

Tags: angular

I have angular 4 app in which I want to get the index of the column from *ngFor 
 and append it to HTML element, I have tried the example in [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) but  it gives me an error

Code:

```
<li *ngFor="let col of Descriptive_FieldsMap;let i = index;">
  <a class="ShowHideColumns" data-columnindex="{{i + 1}}">
      {{col.FieldName}}
     <i id="data-table-col-{{i + 1}}" class="fa fa-minus-square pull-right">
     </i>
  </a>
</li>
```

Error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:↵Can't bind to 'columnindex' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("tive_FieldsMap;let i = index;">
↵
```

Comment: that error seems to say `data-columnindex` is not a valid attribute for `<a></a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `data-columnindex` is not a native attribute of `<a>` tag you must take another approach. Bind with the `attr` directive:

```
<a class="ShowHideColumns" [attr.data-columnindex]="i + 1">
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings

Comment: Thanks a lot, It Worked